# Python Datetime Parse UT timezone

Tags: python, datetime

Trying to parse a date like, "Thu, 22 Oct 2020 17:33:00 UT" with datetime.strptime(). I've tried:

```
datetime.strptime('Thu, 22 Oct 2020 17:33:00 UT', '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')
```

However, it appears 'UT' is not a recognized timezone. Is this possible without any string manipulation? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce that error and getting this, anyone else with similar issues?
`ValueError: time data 'Thu, 22 Oct 2020 17:33:00 UT' does not match format '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z'`

Comment: @VisheshMangla: for me, `%Z` can't parse 'UT' - but that might be platform-dependent

Comment: I' m on a windows PC and you @MrFuppes?

Comment: @VisheshMangla: same. I remember that some strptime format codes worked on Linux but not Windows and vice versa since it falls back to the platfrom's C-implementation

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks for the info @MrFuppes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use dateutil's parser and supply a tzinfos mapping dict:

```
import dateutil

timezone_infos = {"UT": dateutil.tz.UTC}

dt = dateutil.parser.parse('Thu, 22 Oct 2020 17:33:00 UT', tzinfos=timezone_infos)

print(dt)
>>> 2020-10-22 17:33:00+00:00
```